# Hide / Show Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want a simple hide and show `<p></p>` tag with text in it.

I first did this with a simple `*ngIf` directive that hide my tag if my input tag is empty. But what I want is that `<p>` tag is hiding itself if I clear my input tag and show if is there something and rehide again if the input is empty.

So there is my code:

```html
<h2>Bonjour Monsieur {{username}}<span (test)="test()" *ngIf="age != null">, vous avez {{age}} ans</span></h2><br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input [ngModel]="username.toUpperCase()"
               (ngModelChange)="username=$event" name="inputField" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input [(ngModel)]="age"/></td>
    <td>Espagne</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  username: string = "";
  age:number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[hidden]** or ***ngIf** both. Difference is ***ngIf will remove element from DOM** tree and **[hidden] just hides it** but still in DOM tree.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="variable_name" />
<p [hidden]="variable_name == '' ">{{ variable_name}} </p>
```

or

```
<p *ngIf="variable_name != '' ">{{ variable_name}} </p>
```

You can do length check also. 
Ex. `*ngIf="variable_name.length > 0"` or `[hidden]="variable_name.length == 0"`

Comment: I tried to use your method with 

<p [hidden]="variable_name == '' ">{{ variable_name}} </p>
But I have an issue if I compare the variable name to ''. I have to compare it to null.

But even so i tried to compare with null, the <p> tag is not reHidding.

Comment: It should work since [(ngModel)] does two way binding,any changes will be reflected immediately.

Comment: Ok, so I just had a "type" to my input and now it's working properly... whithout it, it's not Hidding my tag.
Thank you Nabin for Helping me =).

Answer (score 0):

Just look if your input value is equal to '':

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username" />
<p *ngIf="username != '' ">{{ username}} </p>
```

More info : [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: Hi, how can I check my value?
I'm used to do a "console.log" but I don't know where to do it with Angular...

Comment: If you want to display the value in the console just to check you can simply make a function and call that function with a button.